# Local behavior of Fourier functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, trigonometry

Let $f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^K \alpha_k cos(x^T\theta_k)$ where $\alpha_k$ are bounded. I need to show that for some $c>0$,
$$f(x^*)-f(x) \geq c \, \|x^*-x\|$$

Comment: You need an absolute value on the  left side.

Answer (score 1):

A special case of your inequality is $|cos x -\cos y| \geq c|x-y|$. If this is true (we can divide by $x-y$ and take limit as $y \to x$ to get) $|\sin x| \geq c$ for all real numbers $x$ which is false. So your inequality is not valid.

Comment: Different way to see this: the left-hand side is bounded, the right-hand side is not.